# Why we use go mod download before build go application?

Tags: go

When people make docker file of go application with module, most of them make like this.

```
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build
```

But when I tried the commands below, it also works well.

```
COPY . .
RUN go build
```

So, what's the difference?
Is there any advantages using `go mod download` command?

Answer (score 6):

***Go 1.11*** introduced the `go mod download` command, which takes ***go.mod*** and ***go.sum*** files and downloads the dependencies from them instead of using the source code. As these files don’t change frequently (unless you are updating the dependencies), they can be simply cached by the `COPY` command from ***Dockerfile***.

Comment: I think i understood what's difference. If i make dockerfile without go mod download command and just go build, actually the output of dockerfile will be same. But without go mod download, go runtime should search my source code ( import part of each .go file) and it take more time than with go mod download command. Am i right??

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done to better use the cache. The dependencies do not change so often as the program itself. Doing the download in a separate step allows this layer to be cached. Repeated builds will then be much faster.